# What happen if broadcast is made to first and last address of other network?

Tags: subnet, ip-address, broadcast

- Broadcast to network id

  What happens if you broadcast to the first IP of another network ?
- broadcast to broadcast id of another network

  What happens if you broadcast to the last IP of another network ?

> ***Note:*** From outside the network or from another network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IP, a *directed broadcast* is defined as the network address with all host-part bits set to 1, e.g. 192.168.0.255 for the 192.168.0.0/24 network or 192.168.3.255 for the 192.168.0.0/22 network. You cannot send a broadcast to an IP address, only to a network.

Directed broadcasts may be forwarded between networks like unicasts. Once it arrives at the destination network, the last hop router translates it to a local L2 broadcast.

Note that most routers drop directed broadcasts by default and only forward them as configured. Also, not all destination networks may support local broadcasts (the common Ethernet does though).